# Programa Euros, donde introduces una cantidad y te devuelve los billetes y monedas necesarias para cubrir dicha cantidad

Tags: java

He creado un programa que pide al usuario una cantidad en euros y calcula el número de billetes necesario para cubrir dicha cantidad y el resto en monedas de 1, 2, 0.5, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01. Los tipos de billetes son: 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10 y 5.

El caso es que funciona pero no del todo bien ya que si pongo por ejemplo 257,27 me devuelve:
Hay 1.0 billetes de: 200.0 Euros
Hay 1.0 billetes de: 50.0 Euros
Hay 1.0 billetes de: 5.0 Euros
Hay 1.0 monedas de: 2.0 Euros
Hay 1.0 monedas de: 0.2 Euros
Hay 1.0 monedas de: 0.05 Euros
Hay 1.0 monedas de: 0.01 Euros

Donde vemos que falta 1 centimo de euro o lo que es lo mismo tendría que haber puesto 2 monedas de 2 centimos (0.02)

Adjunto mi código a ver si alguien ve que estoy haciendo mal.

Muchas gracias de antemano y espero que os sirva de algo y os guste, un saludo.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Euroscompleto {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Declaro variable que contendra el valor a devolver

        double importe = 0;

        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Ingresa el cambio a devolver:");

                importe = sc.nextDouble();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Introduciste un dato erroneo.");

                System.out.println("");

                sc.nextLine();
            }
        }

        while (importe <= 0);

        calcular(importe);
        sc.close();
    }

    // Método para calcular
    public static void calcular(double importe) {

        // Indicamos todas las monedas posibles

        double[] monedas = { 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01 };

        // Creamos un array con 0 de longitud igual a la cantidad de monedas

        // Este array contendra las monedas a devolver

        double[] devolver = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        // Recorremos todas las monedas

        for (int i = 0; i < monedas.length; i++) {

            // Si el importe actual, es superior a la moneda

            if (importe >= monedas[i]) {

                // obtenemos cantidad de monedas

                devolver[i] = Math.floor(importe / monedas[i]);

                // actualizamos el valor del importe que nos queda por didivir

                importe = importe - (devolver[i] * monedas[i]);
            }
        }

        // Bucle para mostrar el resultado

        for (int i = 0; i < monedas.length; i++) {

            if (devolver[i] > 0) {

                if (monedas[i] > 2) {

                    // Indicamos que es un billete
                    System.out.println("Hay " + devolver[i] + " billetes de: " + monedas[i] + " Euros");

                } else {

                    // Indicamos que es una moneda
                    System.out.println("Hay " + devolver[i] + " monedas de: " + monedas[i] + " Euros");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando trabajas con operaciones con números decimales tienes que tener cuidado, esto se debe a que la computadora realiza los cálculos en binario, imprime el valor de  `importe` para que puedas verificar cual es el resultado

```
importe = importe - (devolver[i] * monedas[i]);
System.out.println("Importe: "+importe);
```

El valor de la primera salida debería ser: `57.27` pero en su lugar arroja `57.26999999999998`

La solución para este caso es usar [BigDecimal](https://www.javamexico.org/index.php?q=blogs/luxspes/por_que_usar_bigdecimal_y_no_double_para_calculos_aritmeticos_financieros)
Cambia la siguiente línea de código

```
importe = importe - (devolver[i] * monedas[i]);
```

Por estas líneas de código

```
//Convertimos la multiplicación a un BigDecimal
BigDecimal bd=BigDecimal.valueOf((devolver[i] * monedas[i])); 

//Convertimos importe anterior a BigDecimal, restamos la mulplicación y
// por último convertimos el resultado a double para poder hacer: if(importe >= monedas[i])
importe=BigDecimal.valueOf(importe).subtract(bd).doubleValue();
```

Comment: Hola Joshin, muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, lo acabo de aplicar y funciona perfectamente. Efectivamente cuando he estado con el Debugger de Eclipse veia esas cantidades que dices --> "El valor de la primera salida debería ser: 57.27 pero en su lugar arroja 57.26999999999998" y sabía que ese era el fallo pero no se me había ocurrido usar BigDecimal. Te agradezco mucho tu ayuda, un abrazo.

Comment: @RobertGutiérrez, marca la respuesta como aceptada y dale un voto si te sirvio

Comment: Acabo de marcar la respuesta como aceptada, perdón pero aunque tengo la cuenta de stackoverflow hace mucho todavía hay cosas que estoy descubriendo, un saludo.

Comment: Acabo de subir a GitHub el programa de Euros Completo después de bastantes pruebas, pero si encontráis fallos o mejoras que no se me hayan ocurrido podéis decírmelo y lo sigo retocando.

Muchas gracias a Joshin, por el aporte al fallo del céntimo solucionado con BigDecimal.

Os comparto el enlace para que lo podáis descargar.

https://github.com/RNutM/DAM1-PROG-U1/blob/main/ProgUnidad1/src/extras/Euroscompleto.java

Un saludo.